# SubString across different string lengths

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SUBSTRING command:

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(FileName, CHARINDEX('-', FileName, 0)+1, CHARINDEX('-', FileName, 0)-7 )))
```

and have file paths like the below:

```
"C:\James\AAA(9) - V0001514 MR J BLOGGS.pdf"    returns "V0001514"
"C:\James\test(100) - V0001585 MRS A SMITH.pdf  returns "V0001585 MR"
```

The first one returns the correct result, but the second returns extra characters. Does anyone see a way of ensuring the V* number is always returned correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have fixed your data length by -7

You could try :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (@DATA, CHARINDEX('-', @DATA)+1, 
           CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('-', @DATA)+1, LEN(@DATA)))))
```

Result :

```
"C:\James\AAA(9) - V0001514 MR J BLOGGS.pdf"    returns "V0001514"
"C:\James\test(100) - V0001585 MRS A SMITH.pdf  returns "V0001585"
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to give me the best result based off the format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula.

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(FileName, CHARINDEX('-', FileName, 0)+1, 7 )))
```

Sample:

```
DECLARE @FileName1 VARCHAR(255) = 'C:\James\AAA(9) - V0001514 MR J BLOGGS.pdf"    returns "V0001514'

DECLARE @FileName2 VARCHAR(255) = 'C:\James\test(100) - V0001585 MRS A SMITH.pdf  returns "V0001585 MR'


SELECT 
RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@FileName1, CHARINDEX('-', @FileName1, 0)+1, 7 ))) F1,
RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@FileName2, CHARINDEX('-', @FileName2, 0)+1, 7 ))) F2
```

Result:

```
F1      F2
------- -------
V00015  V00015
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, hope it helps you:

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(100)='C:\James\AAA(9) - V0001514 MR J BLOGGS.pdf'
SELECT @FileName=SUBSTRING(@FileName,CHARINDEX('-',@FileName)+2,LEN(@FileName)-CHARINDEX('-',@FileName))
SELECT LEFT(@FileName,CHARINDEX(' ',@FileName)-1)
```